# How to sort on a field numerically

Tags: linux, sort

I am trying to sort a file called "Team_James" numerically by the last column, and then I would like to save the output as a new file called "file3".

I tried the command `sort Team_James | > s3`, but I don't know how to do it, and I don't even know what `-k` is! 
I have been looking everywhere on the Internet.

What am I doing wrong?

Here what the output of my command `cat Team_James`

```
Pam Murray      4    657-4324  18
Jim Brown       8    467-8743  22
Jim Roberts     17   728-8295  9
Joyce Murray    7    235-1432  13
```

Comment: try `sort -k 4,4n Team_James >file3`

Comment: Hello @Anonymous what is the expected output?

Comment: Hello @Goro trying to get the last field into numeric order

Comment: Sorry @steve but it didn't work. Trying to get the last field in numeric order.

Comment: Are those tabs separating the names from ... whatever the next field is?

Comment: Might you have a player with a middle name listed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the table, in column#1 there are spaces between first name and last name. This means, `sort` will consider the first and last names two separate columns. As a result, the last column of the input table is #5. The command below, assume that all the names provided in column #1 are first/last and there are no middle names.

```
cat Team_James | sort -s -n -k 5.1 > file3
Jim Roberts     17   728-8295  9
Joyce Murray    7    235-1432  13
Pam Murray      4    657-4324  18
Jim Brown       8    467-8743  22
```

```
-n, --numeric-sort   compare according to string numerical value  
-s, --stable         stabilize sort by disabling last-resort comparison  
-k, --key=POS1[,POS2]  
      start a key at POS1 (origin 1), end it at POS2 (default end of  
      line).  See POS syntax above.
```

Comment: Yes, But once I've done that I need to send it to file3

Comment: @Anonymous what do you mean send it to file3? By email? or save it in a new file called file3? If yo mean save the output  as file3 please see the edits. if by email I can revise again ;-)

Comment: Thank you for solving the problem I was stuck at this for a while.

Comment: You are welcome ;-) see k explaination